# Is it possible to make any CSS element behave like <pre>

Tags: html, css, pre

I am loading some content inside an iframe.  I want this content to behave as-if it was inside a `<pre>` tag - namely for it to respect line breaks.  I am using javascript to set the style of the body element of this iframe.

I am wondering if it would be possible to set a particular style that will cause the body of this iframe to act like it's inside `<pre/>`.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

you can find the default setting or how they're suppose to be at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html just apply the same style to the element you want to behave as a pre element and voila you're done

p.s. which is basically

```
pre{ white-space: pre ; display: block; unicode-bidi: embed }
```

Comment: This is great! After reviewing the link, the property `font-family: monospace;` was missed. Its not really needed, but worth mentioning.

Answer (score 42):

If you're only interested in preserving line breaks but not whitespace then I suggest using:

```
body {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

This will collapse multiple consecutive white space characters into one but preserve line breaks. The downside is that it's only supported in IE versions 8 and up.

Answer (score 15):

Try setting the element's `white-space` style to a value of `pre`.

```
body {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want it to act on linebreaks like `pre`, use the css: `white-space: pre`