# Replacing line breaks in DIV jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, string, replace, width

I can't get and replace line breaks in DIV element.

I need to get same form of text like it is in `div`, but I must replace new lines with `< br >`

I have textarea and with jQuery I am copying text to `< div id="text1">` , div has limited width ant text in div is automatically breaks to new line... and I need to get text from `< div id="text1">` where the line breaks is replaced by `< br>`

HTML code:

```
<div id="text1" style="width:80px;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy
nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna 
aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit
lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
var result = $('text1').html();
result = result.replace(/\n/g,'<br>');
result = result.replace(/\r/g,'<br>');
```

Target OUTPUT:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor<br> sit amet,consectetuer <br> adipiscing....
```

The div has **width 80px** , so it automatically breaks the line.

Nothing of replace ***/r /n*** jQuery didn't work.

Thanks for any responses

Comment: HTML doesn't care about your linebreaks, use `<br>` for actual linebreaks, or `white-space : nowrap` to get rid of them ?

Comment: And is that a typo ? `$("#text1")`, `$("text1")` would obviously return nothing

Comment: I need get same form of text like in div, but i must replace new lines with <br>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WGsZy/1/

Comment: $("#text1").html(); returns to me - **"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...** but i need replace breaks line with <br>

Comment: OK what is your expected output or at what point do you define a break in your sample text?

Comment: Now i understand you better. For the benefit of other SO, can you update your question with this explanation

Comment: If I may reiterate what you said, 1) you fetch some strings and append it to your <div>. Due to the width limit on your <div>, long text continue on a new line (remember text is continuous). 2) all you want is to retrieve the text as continuous by removing the break <br>

Comment: Chelseawillrecover -thanks for help

Comment: I think that you are trying to mimic the pre element. If yes, and you would like a CSS solution, check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560038/is-it-possible-to-make-any-css-element-behave-like-pre

Comment: Really thanks, but it was no helping... i must try to find other way to do it