# How to cause each break line in HTML to appear as break line in the browser?

Tags: html, css

Having  - `HTML` and its `CSS` -

**HTML -**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/breakLineInBrowser.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <p>
     Line 1. 
     Line 2.
     Line 3.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS -**

```
p {

}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rgQ6f/)

In the browser it appears as  -

```
Line 1. Line 2. Line 3.
```

Which `CSS` property have I add into the `p {}` in order to get it display as -

```
Line 1. 
Line 2.
Line 3.
```

?

(I don't look for solution with `</br>` in the HTML)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `white-space` property of css.

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have three options.

1. Using `<pre>` HTML tag.

   ```
   <p>
    <pre> 
     Line 1. 
     Line 2. 
     Line 3. 
    </pre> 
   </p>
   ```
2. Using `<br\>` HTML tag

   ```
   <p> 
    Line 1.<br/> 
    Line 2.<br/> 
    Line 3.<br/> 
   </p>
   ```
3. Or using css styles

   ```
   <p style="white-space: pre-line;">
   line1
   line2
   line3
   </p>
   ```

Anyway please read other answers too.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the paragraph?

```
<p>Line 1.</p>
<p>Line 2.</p>
<p>Line 3.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you search is the `pre`-Element. It's css counterpart is

```
pre{ white-space: pre ; display: block; unicode-bidi: embed }
```

(As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560038/is-it-possible-to-make-any-css-element-behave-like-pre))